# How to Replace <div> tags On Access Memo Data Type Before Exporting to Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I'm trying to export my Data from an Access Query to an Excel Spreadsheet. I managed to do this, but once I exported these data from access to excel; Memo data type fields have  tags on these excel cells.

I want to export all my Memo data type fields in excel cells without the  tags.

Here is the sample of My code on MS Access. 
Dim stQueryDef As DAO.QueryDef
    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    'On Error Resume Next

```
Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set stQueryDef = dbs.QueryDefs("MyQuery")
Set rst = stQueryDef.OpenRecordset

Dim xlApp As Object
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
With xlApp
    .Visible = True
    .Workbooks.Add
    .Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    .Activesheet.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst
    For i = 1 To rst.Fields.Count
        xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, i) = rst.Fields(i - 1).Name
    Next i
    xlApp.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With
```

And this is the sample result of my Exported Data.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The google search "ms access strip html tags" finds that the function Plaintext() removes the undesired tags. ;)
Graham R Seach has also written some code to remove them.

Comment: Hi thank you for your feedback, but can you please tell me where should I put this Function on my Code?

Comment: Hi for those who may Encounter the same scenario as me. 

I put the PlainText() function within my Query String. 

Sample: Select PlainText(tblName.tblColumName) From tblName